# Is there a way to design a board to select between 18V or 15V or 12V other than jumpers?

Tags: pcb-design, gate-driving

I am trying to design a gate driver and want the flexablity to choose between 12V, 15V or 18V. Also I want to put multiple gate drivers and same thing want the flexablity to use one of them or 2 of them etc. Currently the only way I can think of doing this is via jumpers. is there a "better" way ? By better I mean a BKM or a standard way of designing with such requirements? I am sure I am not the only person thinking about this ? I scoured the web for something like this but did not find anything relevant, perhaps I was not using the proper words. I used like selecting path, or selecting voltage or alternative paths/routes. Non returned something even close to what I am looking for.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: hint: a jumper is nothing more than a switch

Comment: Please edit into your question: 12/15/18 V of gate driver supply voltage, or of "gate voltage"? Up to 2023, there should be few devices not tolerating a "gate voltage" of 18 V. What I see as advantages to driving a gate to, say 10 V instead of to close to driver supply is slim. (Slightly less gate charge/driver current/\$t_{off}\$ - anything else?)

Comment: What does "BKM" mean?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses.  I am not sure if I am doing this proper way but here goes..

Comment: BKM = Best Known Method.
Apologies for not being super clear.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem in industrial controls some years back, there was 120VAC, 240VAC, 50Hz and 60Hz and the Japanese used 100VAC 50Hz (or 60Hz) and 200VAC 50Hz (or 60Hz). Transformer taps and oversizing the transformer so it wouldn't overheat on 50Hz solved most of the problem.

Universal (switching) power supplies that can accept 85~250VAC 50/60Hz dealt with it more elegantly (although at some cost in components, complexity and transient immunity).

Perhaps you can design your gate driver to be voltage-agnostic over that 12-18V range.

As far as changing what are essentially signal paths, there are many ways to achieve that. I would suggest you consider the user first in that if you do something that requires fewer components or whatever but requires documentation and perhaps equipment to configure, that's going to generate a lot of bad karma in the future if the users can't find how to do it easily. Something documented right on the PCB might be better, whatever it is.

You can buy PCB mount switches such as DIP switches and rotary selector switches. Sometimes they are useful if the cost can be justified (and the users are smart enough to do the configuration). Of course your design should be tolerant of incorrect configuration so at least it's not possible to damage it without trying really hard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. yes I am trying to find a way to change a signal path as needed. 
I am trying to build a board where I can re-route signals when the gate driver is damaged, to a new driver without having remove and solder. Am I making any sense ? 
Is something that is done when experimenting ? I am relatively new to PCB design.
I am trying to drive a series wound DC motor and the gate

Comment: If you are experimenting, and frying parts in the process, jumpers (like jumper blocks, which just require a header to be soldered to the board) make the most sense to me. They cost little, don't greatly affect non-RF signals and isolate moderate voltages and currents pretty much perfectly. If you are killing gate drivers it's possibly related to layout in the power circuit and adding complexity may obscure rather than illuminate where the issues are.

Comment: Just to close this thread can you comment in more details about other ways to change signal path or select between components ?